# GnuPlot - Plot one variable and its multiple properties

Tags: plot, gnuplot, multiple-columns, correlation

I have a data file in csv format which looks like this:

## NodeID  Prop1  Prop2 Prop3

1,        0.5,    0.5,   4

2,        0.3,    0.7,   5

I want to show correlation of different properties for every nodeID I have.
I want to plot property 1 on X-axis and property 2 on y-axis and similary for Property 1 vs property 3.
This is to show for one node how different properties look like. I have around 2500 nodes.

Is it possible to plot something like this in Gnuplot?

I tried using the variable keyword but I am not sure it is convincing enough.

plot 'localView.csv' using 2:3:4 w points ps variable lc palette

Any hints or help w.r.t this will be highly appreciated
Thanks!

Comment: That is a very general question... Any hints about what you exactly want to stress? How many nodeIDs do you have to show? How many properties. Maybe you could use the `parallelaxes` feature (available only in version 5, see http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_cvs/parallel.html

Answer (score 0):

How about plotting prop2 and prop3 separately?

This uses the same X and Y axes for prop2 and prop3:

```
plot 'localView.csv' using 2:3 w points ps variable pt 1 lc palette,\
'localView.csv' using 2:4 w points ps variable pt 2 lc palette}
```

or have two different Y axes for prop2 and prop3:

```
plot 'localView.csv' using 2:3 w points ps variable pt 1 lc palette,\
'localView.csv' using 2:4 w points ps variable pt 2 lc palette axes x1y2
```